# Laravel 8 setting up supervisor .conf file for DDEV development

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, wsl-2, ddev

I am trying to set-up a supervisor to process a queue. I am pretty sure it has to do with the scope the .conf is running in due to DDEV but I am not 100% sure.

Here is my current `.conf`

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work redis
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
user=www-data
numprocs=5
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/user/app/workers.log
```

Running in this directory `/var/www/html` I got this error:

```
supervisor: couldn't chdir to /var/www/html: ENOENT
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

**Other things I have tried**

I have tried running in directory `/home/user/app/artisan` and that actually works kinda. It does start workers but they are not listening on the right scope cause of DDEV it needs to be in the `/var/www/html` directory which is also where I ssh via `ddev ssh`. Speaking of which I have also already tried changing the .conf to

```
directory=/home/user/app
command=ddev exec php artisan queue:work redis
```

I got an error about it not recognizing ddev command but it runs fine from command line.

If any additional information is needed let me know.

Comment: Please try the community answer to this question, which is sorted out in https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/web-container-dockerfiles/laravel-queue-worker - if that doesn't do it for you, you might want to follow up with an issue in ddev-contrib, mentioning @karlshea, who created that recipe.

Answer (score -1):

Once the configuration file has been created, you may update the Supervisor configuration and start the processes using the following commands:

```
sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*
```

For more information on Supervisor, Please Check Here - http://supervisord.org/index.html

Comment: I've tried that no luck. Tried it after every change I attempted as well.